# How do I transfer some data from one node to another in C++ Linkedlist Queue?

Tags: c++

I am sorry for posting the entire code, but I am having a real hard time while getting specific data from each node and transfer the entire data to a whole new node in the function named "Enqueue". I tried adding a watcher to see what my program is doing, it gets stuck in the "Enqueue" function at the if-statement "if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)". Can someone please point my problem what is my mistake? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int numb_persons_category1 = 0;
int numb_persons_category2 = 0;
int numb_persons_category0 = 0;


class Queue
{

    struct node
    {
        string name, date;
        int room;
        node *next;
    };

    node *front;
    node *rear;

public:

    Queue()
    {
        front = NULL;
        rear = NULL;
    }

    void Enqueue(string _name, string _date, int _room)
    {
        node *p = new node;
        p -> name = _name;
        p -> date = _date;
        p -> room = _room;
        p -> next = NULL;

        if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)
        {
            front = rear = p;
            return;
        }

        rear->next = p;
        rear = p;
    }

    void Dequeue()
    {
        node *temp = front;

        if (front == NULL)
            return;
        if (front == rear)
        {
            front = rear = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            front = front->next;
        }

        free(temp);
    }

    int Front()
    {
        if(front == NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Queue is empty\n";
        }
        return front->room;
    }

    bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return front == NULL;
    }

    void populate(Queue *any_queue, int _room, int numb_persons_category)
    {
        node *any_node = front;

        while(any_node != NULL)
        {
            if (_room == 1)
            {
                any_queue->Enqueue(any_node->name, any_node->date, any_node->room);
                cout<<"Name: "<<any_node->name<<endl;
                cout<<"Last Visit: "<<any_node->date<<endl;
                cout<<"Room: "<<any_node->room<<endl;
                cout<<any_node->name<<" must be sent to "<<_room<<endl;
                numb_persons_category++;
            }
            else if (_room == 2)
            {
                any_queue->Enqueue(any_node->name, any_node->date, any_node->room);
                cout<<"Name: "<<any_node->name<<endl;
                cout<<"Last Visit: "<<any_node->date<<endl;
                cout<<"Room: "<<any_node->room<<endl;
                cout<<any_node->name<<" must be sent to "<<_room<<endl;
                numb_persons_category++;
            }
            else if (_room == 0)
            {
                any_queue->Enqueue(any_node->name, any_node->date, any_node->room);
                cout<<"Name: "<<any_node->name<<endl;
                cout<<"Last Visit: "<<any_node->date<<endl;
                cout<<"Room: "<<any_node->room<<endl;
                cout<<any_node->name<<" must be sent to "<<_room<<endl;
                numb_persons_category++;
            }

            cout<<endl<<endl;
            any_node = any_node->next;
        }
    }

    void Print()
    {
        //If you are using Windows, uncomment the line of code that says system("cls");
        //I have added the line of code as comment since I am using a non-Windows machine.
        //system("cls");

        //It doesn't matter if you don't really care about the output of my program anyway
        //It works in both cases.. But I am just trying to clear things up for the user :)

        node* temp = front;
        while(temp != NULL) {
            cout<<"Name: "<<temp->name<<endl;
            cout<<"Last Visit: "<<temp->date<<endl;
            cout<<"Room: "<<temp->room<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Number of patients in category 0: "<<numb_persons_category0<<endl;
        cout<<"Number of patients in category 1: "<<numb_persons_category1<<endl;
        cout<<"Number of patients in category 2: "<<numb_persons_category2<<endl;
    }


};

Queue *obj_category1;
Queue *obj_category2;
Queue *obj_category0;

void room(string _name, string _date, int _room, Queue *obj)
{
    switch (_room)
    {
        case 1:
            obj->populate(obj_category1, _room, numb_persons_category1);
            break;           

        case 2:
            obj->populate(obj_category2, _room, numb_persons_category2);
            cout<<_name<<" must be sent to "<<_room<<endl;
            numb_persons_category2++;
            break;

        case 0:
            obj->populate(obj_category0, _room, numb_persons_category0);
            cout<<_name<<" must be sent to "<<_room<<endl;
            numb_persons_category0++;
            break;

        default: 
            cout<<"Room is unavailable!\n\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    Queue *obj = new Queue();

    int room_number;
    string name, date;
    char user_visit;

    char run = 'y';

    while (run == 'y')
    {
        cout<<"Enter name: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Is this your first visit? (Y/N): ";
        cin>>user_visit;

        if (user_visit == 'n')
        {
            cout<<"Enter your last visit (MM/DD/YY): ";
            cin>>date;
        }
        else
        {
            date = "0/0/0";
        }

        cout<<"Enter room: ";
        cin>>room_number;
        cout<<"\n\n\n";
        obj->Enqueue(name, date, room_number);

        room(name, date, room_number, obj);

        cout<<"Continue? (Y/N): ";
        cin>>run;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating nodes with `new` and deallocating them with `free`. 
At least that's one of the bugs, there might be more. Try stepping 
through 
your code with a debugger.

note; `new` goes with `delete`, and is preferable in C++ 
`malloc` goes with `free` and is C-style

Answer (score 0):

First, please indent the entire program code, not only the nested blocks.
Second, you have:

```
Queue *obj_category1; // which is null as global var initialized by default

obj->populate(obj_category1, _room, numb_persons_category1); // here you pass that null pointer and then it is accessed in the line the debugger complaining about
```

And yes, 'new' should be matched with 'delete' not 'free' as it was correctly pointed out already. But that is not the reason for specific error and will trigger the error if specific destructor not called. That is not nice in this case but not lethal.